# postgres add constraint to ensure one column is not null if another column is not null

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Postgres 9.3

I have two integer type columns 'a' and 'b'. Valid options are:

- 'a' is null, 'b' is null
- 'a' is not null, 'b' is null
- 'a' is not null, 'b' is not null

I'm trying to add a check/constraint which prevents the invalid option:

- 'a' is null, 'b' is not null

I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your condition is actually a logical implication: if `a is null` then `b is null`. From our symbolic logic course (PHIL 140 in my case), we know that:

```
(P -> Q) <-> (-P | Q)
```

where `->` is implication and `<->` is logical equivalence.

Applying that to our implication and SQLizing it yields:

```
a is not null or b is null
```

so a simple `check(a is not null or b is null)` constraint is sufficient.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bebee/1

Comment: Shame there's no implication operator, my CHECK constraints are littered with `-- (P -> Q) <-> (-P | Q)` comments to remind myself what the logic is really expressing.

Comment: @muistooshort: you could use `P::int - Q::int <= 0` :) looks a bit more like an implication. But if you really want, use [create operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createoperator.html) to create implication operator

Comment: @shaunc: I try to stay away from adding my own operators, less baggage to carry around that way. I'd probably go with `-P::int + Q::int >= 0` because it is more recognizable because I've used `-P | Q` so many times :)

Comment: Sounds good :) -- just make sure to parenthesize for [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE)

Answer (score 5):

```
create table t (
    a int,
    b int,
    check (
        a is null and b is null
        or
        a is not null and b is null
        or
        a is not null and b is not null
    )
);

insert into t (a, b) values
(null, null),
(1, null),
(1, 1),
(null, 1);
ERROR:  new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "t_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 1).
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I had been trying to check it wasn't the invalid option, rather than checking it was one of the correct options.